# cant get gujarati text from mysql database

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16, utf8-decode

I have database with with gujarati text in it.
I have used utf-8 for displaying using PHP, but cant display the gujarati font.
for example: i have string in gujarati : `u00abfku00fe`
which real font is: `પ્રકાશ`
so, is there any other decoding method to display this text.

Answer (score 1):

you should set charset as utf-8 in both insert and get record from database when you using other characters, like

```
$DB->SetCharSet('utf8');
```

also specify the database table's collation as uft8 general ci

Comment: I have already set collation. ..and i am not going to insert. .i have ready made databae. .i want to just display it

Answer (score 1):

This is my example code, I have wrote here

```
mysql_query("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query("INSERT into TABLENAME VALUES (null,'$chap_sel_sub','$chap_sel_std',N'$chap_name',N'$chap_code',N'$chap_des','$current')");
```